# RDBMS Tree type relationships

Tags: sql, ms-access, rdbms

I am writing a database where I need to sub-divide products in order to store their attributes.  Take two massively different products.  TV's and Fruit.

Both have common attributes, such as a Name, Price and Stock Number.

Fruit would have specific attributes like, SellByDate, CountryofOrigin, Dried/Fresh.
TV's would also have their own attributes, like PowerOutPut, Dimensions, SMART? etc...

I can't store all of these attributes in a single table as I will have a lot of empty fields so to minimize wasted space, I thought I could create a "Parent" Products table and two child tables "TVs" and "Fruit".

Relationship window here:-
http://goo.gl/XRNzjZ

However the one-to-one link from the parent to the child looks wrong.  Is there a standard approach to this?  Any ideas gratefully received.

Using Access2010.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled upon [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). Congrats!

It is the standard approach, so don't worry.